# Typing Checking for a value to be any string except one literal

Tags: python, python-typing

The `Union[X, Y]` type is for when the type can be either `X` or `Y`. I want the opposite when the type must be `X` but never `Y` so either:

- Any `X` but not `Y` where `Y` is a specific sub-class of `X`; or
- Any base type except one particular literal of that base type that should be treated differently.

For example, if there was an `Except` special form equivalent to the inverse of `Union` then I would use:

```python
class Attribute:
    @overload
    def __init__(
        name: Literal["id"] = ...,
        required: Literal[True] = ...,
        null: Literal[False] = ...,
    ) -> None:
        pass

    @overload
    def __init__(
        name: Except[str, Literal["id"]] = ...,
        required: bool = ...,
        null: bool = ...,
    ) -> None:
        pass

    def __init__(
        name: str,
        required: bool = False,
        null: bool = False,
    ) -> None:
        pass
```

In this case, if the `Attribute` has the `name` `"id"` then it should always have the `required` property and should never have the `null` property whereas if it has any other `name` then those properties are optional.

Programmatically, it can be handled within the `__init__` function that if the properties are not the expected values then exceptions are thrown but I would also like to make it explicitly clear during static type checking that `Attribute("id", False, False)` (and other invalid combinations) would not be valid.

Is there any way to specify this during type checking?

Comment: Note that your title says "except one literal", but I don't think that's what you're asking. You're asking how to construct a type hint that would allow any subclass of some class, except a specific subclass (and its descendants, presumably). I don't think there's syntax for that, other than creating a Union of all the allowed subclasses and leaving the disallowed one out - but I'd be interested to see how if proven wrong.

Comment: @Grismar There are two use-cases that are interesting (1) having an overload for sub-type `Y` and an overload for super-type `X` that excludes sub-type `Y` and (2) for having a base type such as `str` or `int` and an overload for one literal of that base type and another overload for all other values of that base type. From a type-checking perspective, I imagine the implementation would be identical. In the first case, yes, you may be able to construct a `Union` type that encompasses all (known) sub-types of `X` that are not `Y` but you cannot do the same for all `str` that are not `"id"`.